# Could you explain these exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I know its a bit harsh to ask this, but I'm studying for an exam and don't really get how this exception works.

```
class Axception extends Exception {}; 
class Bxception extends Axception {}; 

public class Exceptions { 
  public static void main(String [] a) throws Exception { 
        System.out.println("A");    
   try { 
    System.out.println("B"); 
    try { 
     System.out.println("C"); 
     throw new Exception(); 
    } catch (Axception a1) { 
     System.out.println("D"); 
     throw a1; 
    } 
    finally{ 
     System.out.println("E");
 
    } 
    } catch (Bxception e)  { 
    System.out.println("F"); 
    } catch (Exception e)  { 
    System.out.println("G"); 
    }   
    System.out.println("H");  
  } 
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know what is Exception?

Comment: What don't you get about how this works?  What do you think the output will be?  Why?

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?  You surely can't expect anyone to write several pages on what exceptions are about - that information already exists in the Java tutorials.

Comment: From looking at the code it looks more like you are wondering what the output will be and the program flow.  Before explaining how the flow would be can you give an example of what you think  the output would be?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how this code works but it seems someone just answered that. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough so I will do a better job next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output should be A B C E G H

It should be easy to see why order is A B C. After that you throw an object of Exception.
But since you are trying to catch it in a subclass object namely Axception a1, it wont be caught. Hence it won't print D nor it would throw a1. Then finally would be processed no matter what. Hence, a E.

Again you try to catch Exception object in a subclass object namely Bxception e, it wont be caught. Hence it wont print F.

Next you try to catch it in Exception object hence it will be caught and would print G.

Since exception is caught now, method should happily go and print H.

Hence A B C E G H.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: How would this code be executed ?
`catch (Axception a1) { 
     System.out.println("D"); 
     throw a1; 
    }`

Comment: since you are trying to catch it in a subclass object namely Axception a1, it wont be caught.-- meaning it wont execute { System.out.println("D"); throw a1; }